# Alamofire/NSURLSession caching with private Cache-Control and max-age

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but caching is not working when setting `urlRequest.cachePolicy = .useProtocolCachePolicy` and having a cache-header set to private with max-age `"Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=86400";`

Should useProtocolCachePolicy work with private? Or I need to manually override it to public?

Answer (score 0):

I tried following code which worked fine for me,
using  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy.

it expires the cache according to cache-control/max-age in http header response:

I used this helpful [blog](https://www.mobfox.com/blog/handling-nsurlsession-caching-bug/)

here is the code I used:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://yourserver.com"];

NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
        timeoutInterval:60.0
    ];

    if (self.session == nil) {
        NSURLSessionConfiguration * config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue];
    }
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"task transport error %@ / %d", error.domain, (int) error.code);
            return;
        }

        NSHTTPURLResponse * httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
        NSLog(@"task finished with status %d, bytes %zu", (int) httpResponse.statusCode, (size_t) data.length);

        NSDictionary * headers = httpResponse.allHeaderFields;
        NSLog(@"response-headers %@",headers);
    }];

    [task resume];
```